# Need help adding adobe edge animate to wordpress without plugin

Tags: wordpress, adobe, adobe-edge

I have actually done this before but I can not remember how to get this right.  Does anyone know the proper setup or of a tutorial that explains how to set this up without a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

## Getting Adobe Edge Animations to work in WordPress (or any other CMS)

I just did this myself, and posted an article on Codepen about it; http://codepen.io/write/getting-adobe-edge-animations-to-work-in-wordpress

> I've also opened up an issue over at Github; https://github.com/wittnl/Edge-Animate-Runtime/issues/3

### The problem

When EA (Edge Animate) is looking for assets they use relative paths.
This becomes a problem when we're using WordPress, where we need to reference our theme folder, an absolute URL.

#### ERROR 1

The main file edge.x.x.x.js fails loading the right javascript file for the composition. Resulting in a 404, file not found.

#### ERROR 2

The composition specific javascript file that get's loaded by edge.x.x.x.js have relative paths to images etc. Resulting in that no images are loaded.

### What we want

1. Have all our assets stored in our theme folder
2. Have all files load properly and enjoy our animations

### The solution

#### 1) Modify the main javascript file

1. Make your own version of the main javascript file, e.g; `edge.5.0.1-edited.js`
2. Check for `comp.load` and change it so that it loads from our theme folder correctly.

   `comp.load('/wp-content/themes/my-awesome-theme/assets/edge/' + projectPrefix + "/" + projectPrefix + "_edge.js");`

#### 2) Modify the "composition"-specific javascript file

1. Change the variables you need to change (e.g `images`) inside `tools_edge.js` so that it points to your theme folder.

   `var im='/wp-content/themes/my-awesome-theme/assets/edge/tools/images/'`